# How to install and run protractor locally

Tags: windows, automation, installation, protractor

I am new on protractor platform and I tried to install and run the protractor locally on window, but I had no luck yet. Can anybody please tell me the exact step? I am able to install and run it globally.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please follow the instructions on Protractor web site

Answer (score 1):

For you

1. Create an empty folder as project base dir
2. Open a terminal and cd into the new folder
3. Execute `npm init` to generate `package.json`
4. Execute `npm install -S protractor` to install protractor locally and add it into project's dependencies. (you can check `protractor` will appear in package.json)
5. Prepare test script
6. Commit test script with package.json together

For others who want to run you code locally,

1. Clone your code to local
2. Open terminal and cd project base dir
3. Execute `npm install` to install dependencies to local
4. Execute protractor cli to execute test